# Maximal ideals of $Z_6$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

In $Z_n$ I know that $I=<a>$ is a maximal ideal if and only if a is a prime divisor of n.
However according to this, in $Z_6$, <4> is not maximal since 4 is not a devisor of 6. But <4> is equal to <2> which is maximal how is that can anyone clarify this?

Comment: Why is $(2)$ equal to $(4)$ in $\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$?

Comment: <4>={0,2,4}
<2>={0,2,4}

Comment: ''In $\mathbb{Z}_n$, $I = \langle a \rangle$ is a maximal ideal iff $a | n$'' is not correct. Consider $I=\langle 4 \rangle \subseteq \mathbb{Z}_{8}$; You can check 4 is a divisor of 8, and $I = \{0, 4\} \subsetneq \langle2 \rangle = \{0, 2, 4, 6\} \subsetneq \mathbb{Z}_8$.

Comment: Yes you are right I forgot to right (prime devisor) so now although <4> is equal to <2> in Z6 but 4 is not a devisor can we say <4> is maximal since it is equal to <2> ?

Comment: The theorem should be stated as like $\langle d \rangle \subset \mathbb{Z}_n$ is a maximal ideal if $d|n$ and $d$ is prime. Yes, $\langle 4 \rangle = \langle 2 \rangle$ is max ideal in $\mathbb{Z}_6$.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that $4$ is not a divisor of $6$ has nothing to do with $\langle 4\rangle$ being a maximal ideal or not.

The ideals of $\mathbb{Z}_6$ can be described as $\langle k\rangle$ where $k$ is a divisor of $6$, but this is all. In particular, $\langle 4\rangle$ *must* have that form and it turns out that $\langle 4\rangle=\langle 2\rangle$.